# How can I find out the meaning of an error code when unzipping a file using Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a file using perl on linux. The file is password protected, and am looping through possible password in a brute force attack *(yes this is a homework assignment)*

I have isolated and removed ther error code 20992 (bad password), but am still getting another error code which is not listed anywhere in the [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip), and couldn't find anything relevant using The Googles either.

The error is:

```
512  error:  invalid compressed data to inflate secret_brute.txt
```

Has anyone seen this error message? If so, what mean?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@aaaa_zzzz = ("aaaa" .. "zzzz");

foreach(@aaaa_zzzz){
        $output = system("unzip -P $_ -q -o secret_brute.zip");
        if($output  !~ m/20992/){ #  <-- filtering out other error message
                chomp($output);
                print "$_ : $output\n";
        }
}
```

*Edit*

Per request: [Secret_brute.zip](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/secret_brute.zip)

Comment: Do `perldoc -f system` and see what it says about the return value of `system`.

Comment: Great idea - perhaps the error code isn't from `unzip` at all, but from `system`...

Comment: How big is that secret_brute.zip? Can you put it somewhere on the web?

Comment: The name `$output` is misleading because the variable does not hold the output of the `unzip` command but the return value of `system`.

Comment: You really should `use strict; use warnings;`. It is the best way to learn perl, and once you start using it, you'll never want to be without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of [exit codes from unzip](http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#error-codes).

As mentioned, [perldoc -f system](http://perldoc.perl.org) explains how to get the exit value of `unzip`:

> If you'd like to manually inspect `system`'s failure, you can
>   check all possible failure modes by inspecting [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) like this:

```
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

In this case, a value of `512` would map to:

> `2`: A generic error in the zipfile format was detected. Processing may have completed successfully anyway; some broken zipfiles created by other archivers have simple work-arounds.

On the other hand, `20992` would map to:

> `82`: No files were found due to bad decryption password(s). (If even one file is successfully processed, however, the exit status is `1`.)

Comment: Indeed, programming _is_ fun again with Perl.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. Mapping out the messages led me to solve my own problem. As it turns out, when performing the unzip, there can be false positives on passwords-- which lead to trying to unzip the archive and failing: 512 error. The password was in the w*** range, so I ended up suppressing any error messages using `2>/dev/null` in the system command, and giving it 45 min to run!